# Make a dataframe filter a variable so i can set it once and re use

Tags: pyspark

Hi I've got a script that re uses the same filter a few times
something like this:

```
df_filtered = df.filter( col("columnname" == valueparam))
```

how can i make it so i set it once at the top of my script so i can change it easily everywhere it occurs, so something like this:

```
filter_val =  'col("columnname" == valueparam))'
df_filtered = df.filter(filter_val)
```

to be honest Python/pyspark is all very new to me so if i'm going about this the wrong way i'm open to options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1,), (2,),(3,)], ["Test"])
df.show()
valueparam = 3
col_filter = (F.col("Test") == valueparam)
df.filter(col_filter).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+
|Test|
+----+
|   1|
|   2|
|   3|
+----+

+----+
|Test|
+----+
|   3|
+----+
```

Comment: Aaargh, so close! just drop the quotes round the filter, that is annoying. but thank you

Comment: And in case anyone is using type hints in their code and was wondering what the correct type hint for `col_filter` would be: per the [pyspark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.filter) it's `pyspark.sql.Column`.